# How to apply NumericUpDown's Acceleration feature to a regular Button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can I apply an acceleration feature to a regular `Button`? (Like the `NumericUpDown` control's `Acceleration` property). In the image below you can see that I have controls to manipulate the overall size dimensions of a window, and I wish to keep the layout as it is rather than using a `NumericUpDown` control.

For example, on the `>>>` button (increment width 1inch) I wish to accelerate the number displayed in the corresponding `TextBox` when the user keeps the button depressed.

My initial thought was to create a custom `Button` which inherits and/or wraps a `NumericUpDown` control and leverage the existing property on the latter. However, I would still have to fire the appropriate event/property on the underlying `NumericUpDown` control while the button is being held in a depressed state. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: No, you can't easily get to that.  If you need inspiration on how to implement this feature yourself then consider to start at the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UpDownBase.cs,434558e770866e51)

Comment: thanks for the reference - very useful, didn't know that existed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Timer` maybe? VB.net:

```
Private mouseDownTimeElapsed As Integer = 0

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Increment the total time mouse has been depressed
    mouseDownTimeElapsed += 50
    'The following have the same effect as the NumericUpDownAcceleration objects
    If mouseDownTimeElapsed > 2000 Then
        IncrementOverallWidth(10)
    ElseIf mouseDownTimeElapsed > 1000 Then
        IncrementOverallWidth(3)
    ElseIf mouseDownTimeElapsed > 500 Then
        IncrementOverallWidth(1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseDown
    'This check is necessary or a single click won't trigger an increment
    If mouseDownTimeElapsed = 0 Then
        IncrementOverallWidth(1)
    End If
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 50
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseUp
    Timer1.Stop()
    'Reset the mouse down time to zero so the process can start over on next click
    mouseDownTimeElapsed = 0
End Sub
```